# Regex last occurrence which still has keyword after it

Tags: java, regex, selenium

For Java selenium reasons I need the last occurrence of a string that still has a keyword after it:

```
href="something "><br />
href="something else"> <br />
href="INeedThis"> </a> // <- i need this <br />
keyword <br />
href="something else">
```

So I made this:

```
href=\"(?![\s\S]\*?href=\")([\s\S]\*?)\"[\s\S]\*?(?=keyword)
```

Which works if there is no `href="` left after the keyword.
Also the text `"INeedThis"` differs in every situation I intend to use this on.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about what you want to match?

Comment: Little late on the comment, but, I need everything in between the " " 's. so basicly the text INeedThis

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, I think this may do what you need:

```
href=\"([^\"]*?)\"((?!href).)*?(?=keyword)
```

Explanation:

- `href=\"([^\"]*?)\"` - Matches the contents between the `"`s after `href=`

  - `([^\"]*?)` - Lazily matches any character that is NOT a `"`.
- `((?!href).)*?` - Lazily matches any number of characters that are not immediately followed by `href` by using a negative lookahead. Basically ensures that this is the `href` directly before the keyword.
- `(?=keyword)` - Uses a positive lookahead to ensure that the `href` we've matched is immediately followed by the keyword when combined with the negative lookahead that asserts that there are no `href`s between the keyword and the `href` we've matched.

In action: https://regex101.com/r/NCJXbA/1

This pattern will match any number of instances of `href` preceeding the keyword, so that if there are multiple instances of this pattern the matches are all captured.

Comment: That works mostly, but how do I select only the last match?

Answer (score 0):

This regex captures your `"INeedThis"`:

```
(?:.*href="[^"]*")*.*href="([^"]*)"(?=.*keyword)
```

If the input string can contain newlines, as it appears is the case, then you must be sure to enable the `DOTALL` option.

```
String input =
        "href=\"something \">\n"
        + "href=\"something else\">\n"
        + "href=\"INeedThis\">\n"
        + "keyword\n"
        + "href=\"something else\">";

Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(
        "(?:.*href=\"[^\"]*\")*.*href=\"([^\"]*)\"(?=.*keyword)",
        Pattern.DOTALL);

Matcher m = myPattern.matcher(input);

if (m.lookingAt()) { // or maybe m.find(), but not m.matches()
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
} else {
    System.out.println("no match");
}
```

Output:

> INeedThis

Note that this is sensitive to which quotation style is used in the href attributes (as is yours), and it does not accommodate whitespace around the `=` (like yours).

This is also a more general pattern than yours.  As such, it is suitable for extracting the wanted data from input of the form you describe, but it is *not* suitable for simultaneously verifying that the input indeed has exactly that form.

Additionally, if the keyword may appear more than once, then this pattern will select the last candidate string that appears before the last appearance of the keyword, which may occur *after* earlier appearances of the keyword.